# dynamically adding two views one below other

Tags: android

I want to add two views one after the other, I used this way but I am getting an error.
This is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >
<ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"


      >

              <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rel1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

              ></RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rel2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"                  
              ></RelativeLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the two Relative layouts rel1,and rel2 I will add my custom views which are going to be drawn dynamically.

my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout rlstat1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel1);
        RelativeLayout rlstat2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para1 = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                viewWidth, viewHeight);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para2 = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                viewWidth, viewHeight);

        rlstat1.setLayoutParams(para1);
        rlstat1.addView(mView);

        para2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rel1);
        rlstat2.addView(mView2);
```

Here mView and mView2 are two view type which I want to set in the two relative layouts.
ViewWidth and ViewHeight are the width and height of the screen it is running.

The problem:
If only one view is added i.e. mView or mView2 it's showing but if both the views are added(like in above) then only one relative layout is shown.
I want that both of my views get set one below other.
Hope I am clear in my question.Can you please tell me the appropriate  way to do this.

Comment: please don't use relative layout here. Make scrollview the root of your xml and when you use custom views you can reference them in your xml with the packagename.classname. Use a linear layout inside of the scrollview with orientation to vertical...

Comment: Got the solution.It was my fault just forgot to add 

    rlstat2.setLayoutParams(para2);

in my code, anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting layout params to views dynamically in activity and these are new layout params objects, so your rule to add rel2 to below of rel1 gets cleared, instead try:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout rlstat1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel1);
        RelativeLayout rlstat2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para1 = rlStat1.getLayoutParams();

        para1.width=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        para1.height=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para2 = rlStat2.getLayoutParams();

        para2.width=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        para2.height=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        rlstat1.setLayoutParams(para1);
        rlstat1.addView(mView);

        para2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rel1);
        rlstat2.addView(mView2);
```

Comment: but i want the size of rlstat1 and rlstat2 to be the size of screen.

Comment: Got the solution.It was my fault just forgot to add 

    rlstat2.setLayoutParams(para2);

in my code, anyway thanks a lot .

Comment: You need to use LayoutParams for a ViewGroup in order to be able to add rules check this out :

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);